# How to deploy fastapi to google cloud run

Tags: python, gcloud, fastapi, google-cloud-run, buildpack

I have a fastapi app that I want to deploy to google cloud run.

With a gRPC python project, We deploy it as

```sh
gcloud beta run deploy countries --source .
```

But this doesn't deploy as expected. I watched a video that deploying from source uses [Google cloud buildpacks](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks).

Is there anyone with a way of doing that?

My code is like

```py
from typing import List
import geopandas as gpd
from fastapi import FastAPI
from geojson_pydantic.geometries import Geometry
from geojson_pydantic.features import Feature
from pydantic import BaseModel
from shapely.geometry.geo import shape
import json
import shapely

class Country(BaseModel):
    name: str
    code: str
    type: str
    geometry: Feature


app = FastAPI(
    title="Natural Earth Countries",
    description="This is a list of endpoints which you can use to access natural earth data.",
    version="0.0.1",
    docs_url='/',
)

gdf = gpd.read_file('data/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.zip')
gdf['name'] = gdf['ADMIN'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())

@app.get('/countries/all')
def get_all_countries() -> List[Country]:
    return rows_to_countries(gdf)


@app.get('/countries/search/{name}')
def search_countries(name: str):
    name = name.lower()
    subset = gdf.loc[gdf["name"].str.contains(name)]
    return rows_to_countries(subset)

@app.get('/countries/within-boundary')
def countries_intersecting(boundary: Geometry):
    bounds = shape(boundary)
    subset = gdf.loc[gdf.intersects(bounds)]
    return rows_to_countries(subset)


def row_to_country(row):
    return Country(
        name=row["ADMIN"],
        type=row["TYPE"],
        geometry=Feature(geometry=row['geometry']),
        code=row["ADM0_A3"],
    )


def rows_to_countries(gdf):
    return [row_to_country(row) for _, row in gdf.iterrows()]
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: Include your Dockerfile in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley I was trying to find a way of deploying fastapi without using a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 7):

The solution to I've found is creating a Dockerfile

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8

ENV APP_HOME /app

WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker  --threads 8 main:app
```

Then running

```sh
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/countries_fastapi
```

Then after image is submitted to gcloud, running

```
gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/bitnami-oyzgng8y5a/countries_fastapi --platform managed
```

Comment: Why does this use gunicorn to wrap uvicorn? Why are you copying files to $APP_HOME twice?

Comment: @cory I would also think directly running a single uvicorn worker will be better for how Cloud Run works.

Answer (score 0):

What error message do you see when you deploy with the buildpacks? When deploying Python apps, you need to include a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) in the root of your application that declares the command you should use to start the app:

```
web: gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker  --threads 8 main:app
```